# Calculating Time and Space complexity of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to make some benchmarks of few sorting algorithms and compare there performances. 
So what I need to ask is are there any tools out there which will help to monitor Program's time and space complexity.
I did tried to find on Google but search results not leading me to proper direction.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: "Time complexity" and "space complexity" are abstract terms relating to [asymptotic behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-O_notation) of an algorithm.  Presumably what you mean is "run-time" and "memory usage"?  More generally, the term you're looking for is "profiling".

Comment: There are a ton of articles about these topics on the web. Just type "sort algorithms" in a search engine and explore a litte.

Comment: @SamuelRossille: it is probably an homework. Almost nobody wants to mess with sorting algorithms, unless they know a lot what they are doing (and it does not looks like it is the case here)

Comment: haha @akappa no its not a homework, i am doing it for myself to test my sorting technique with the ones already available. So i need to do some bench mark testing to check the efficiency of algo. I intend to do all the work just need to know some info. I know many ppl are fedup with homework questions on this topic but this is not the case here.

Comment: @oli Charleswoth : yes i want to check "run-time" and "memory usage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @OliCharlesworth already pointed out, your question has nothing to do with time/space "complexity": the time complexity is an asymptotic measure of how many steps your algorithm takes in an ideal computational model, like the [RAM machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access_machine) or the [Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) one.

What you really want to do is just to measure the amount of time and space taken by the **concrete implementation** of your algorithm. This, of course, depends on which language you are using to do that.
If you are using something which compiles to executables, you might be interested in the [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) suite of tools, in particular Massif (memory profiler) and Callgrind (time profiler).

Comment: i intend to implement algorithms in C and Java and do the benchmark testings. Thanks for help that helped a lot. :)